# Modify only array from the state object

Tags: reactjs

I have  a state object that contains an object and I am trying to add/remove items from it without success:

```
const [currentUser,setCurrentUser]=useState(Object)
```

and the Object looks like:

```
{username:"username",
array:[0,...,N]}
```

This tells me that it does not recognize the array...

```
setCurrentUser([...currentUser.array,index])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your state contains an array, but your code shows it contains an Object instead. So to update only the array inside the object, you should do:

`setCurrentUser({...currentUser, array: [...currentUser.array, index]})`

Comment: Thank you! I did mean an Object, sorry for that. I edited so it is clear.